# Difference between pd.read_csv ("./filename.csv") and pd.read_csv ("filename.csv")

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When I learn pandas, I found there is code written like `pd.read_csv("./filename.csv")` when they want to load data. But usually we just write like `pd.read_csv("filename.csv")` right?

So what's the difference between `pd.read_csv("./filename.csv")` and `pd.read_csv("filename.csv")`.

Why is there need for "./" before the filename ?

Comment: `'./'` should mean parent folder. 
So if your current working directory is 'C:/Users/abcd'
by doing '`./'` this would lead you to be on 'C:/Users'

Comment: @sammy is wrong.  `./` means the current folder.  There is no difference between 'filename.csv' and './filename.csv'.  Some Linux users get in the habit of using ./x, because we have to type that a command line to execute a local program 'x'.

Comment: Oh yeah i confused `./` with `../` sorry

Comment: this is not **pandas** this is understanding a Unix / Linux type file system and locators that exist within this very robust mature approach

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thank you so much.